# Can the GAMS run in Google Cloud if used with its Python API

Tags: python, flask, optimization, gcloud, gams-math

So, I am working on a project that has a backend optimization algorithm written in [GAMS](https://www.gams.com/).
The ideal solution is to be able to use this GAMS code that is already written with the python API for GAMS. I want to be able to call this code through an HTTP request and run the algorithm, so I wanted to make a Flask server for this. Ideally, it could run in Google's App Engine, but GAMS software must be installed.
I am not sure if this is possible on App Engine, or if it can be done in a Google instance.
The data input would be from CSV's in google cloud storage and the output would be put there as well.

I was wondering if anyone has tried this before or if you know more about Google cloud and think this will or will not work. I could not find much about this online.

Comment: This might be interesting for you: https://gams.com/miro/engine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question would benefit from more detail and including references e.g. Is this [GAMS](https://www.gams.com/products/introduction/)?

App Engine standard is opinionated and it *may* not (don't know) be possible for you to bundle GAMS as part of a Python deployment to App Engine standard.

However, if you were willing to bundle a Python (Flask) server and GAMS together, it's possible you could containerize the solution and run it on App Engine flexible as a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes).

Alternatives exist and may be better matches to your needs including detaching the (Flask) frontend server from the GAMS backend (?) and deploying these on App Engine (or possibly Cloud using Functions, Cloud Run, Compute Engine etc.).

Someone who has done this may be willing to provide additional pointers|guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to this problem, I found, was to get rid of GAMS entirely.
There were many ways I wished to integrate this model into my web app, so I translated the model to Python using PyOMO. The performance was slightly affected, but the model can now be run in Google Cloud.

I set up the model in a Flask server and now built a REST API around it for use in the web app.